# Will a pending stock buy/sell order get invalidated if the symbol or its structure changes (e.g. split)?

Tags: after-hours-trading

When placing orders for buying or selling ETF stocks, will a pending order get invalidated if there's a stock split, reverse split, or some other form of symbol/name change happen while the order is pending?

On QTrade (online brokerage), I typically place the order by typing the symbol name, but I'm hoping the actual order gets filed electronically using something more immutable. How does that work? [ISINs](https://www.investopedia.com/terms/i/isin.asp#) seem like they could help with this, but there's no clear indication that this is what gets used behind the scenes.

This is probably irrelevant for orders which are fulfilled during trading hours, but for long-standing orders, I can imagine it could be a problem.

(In case the behaviour is determined by rules of the stock exchange, I'm talking about TSX and NYSE, mostly)